# How to extract column names into a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dummy-variable

I am new to python and would appreciate if someone could help on this:

I would like to apply one hot encoding to dataframe:

```
features_specs_train_ohe = pd.get_dummies(features_specs_train)
```

which should result in a new dataframe (features_specs_train_ohe).

However, when I apply

```
features = list(features_specs_train_ohe.columns)
```

i get the error

> 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'.

Why is this? Shouldn't `features_specs_train_ohe` be dataframe? I would appreciate help on how to extract column names into feature list.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: please show a example of : `print(features_specs_train_ohe)`

Comment: SK_ID_CURR  AMT_ANNUITY  AMT_CREDIT  AMT_GOODS_PRICE  AMT_INCOME_TOTAL  \
0         100002      24700.5    406597.5         351000.0          202500.0   
1         100003      35698.5   1293502.5        1129500.0          270000.0   
2         100004       6750.0    135000.0         135000.0           67500.0   
3         100006      29686.5    312682.5         297000.0          135000.0

Comment: Check that your code is executed as above without anything else called.  pd.get_dummies does indeed return a pd.DataFrame, even when passed a numpy array.  I don't know how `features_specs_train_ohe` could be a numpy array

Comment: I think imputer might be the reason... 0


I used SimpleImputer on my dataframe, which obviously contained some NaN (as a result of ohe) because the number of features before the imputation was larger than that after it.

Is there any way I can find out which features were removed? I did specify verbose =1 in my imputation code, but did not get any details on feature reduction.